# font breaks when click next page in bxSlider

Tags: css, fonts, bxslider

Issue appear only in Chrome.

When clicking next-arrow font (on next slide) become a little bit blurred

[Live example of the problem](http://www.meteoprog.kz/en/weather/Astana/)

it is not the first time i saw this issue.

Why it works like this and what should be done to does not face a similar problem?

normal font: [screenshot](http://joxi.ru/bmoWOa6fKWD7my)

blurred font after next-arrow clicked: [screenshot](http://joxi.ru/DrlQOL7CPELQmP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not a bug with BxSlider or your code. it's a Chrome bug, which is DirectWrite engine for newly version of Chrome, that may occur on some windows's users. to turn it off, please check up this link [Fixing blurry font in Chrome](http://www.neatorama.com/2014/09/05/Chromes-Font-Looks-Blurry-to-You-Heres-How-To-Fix-It/)

Comment: I made screenshots on Ubuntu... the same issue under Linux Mint...no only on Windows.

Comment: I have tested your website on Chrome on windows 7 and it worked perfectly without blurry font. have you tried turning off DirectWrite engine or opening your website on another computer ?

Comment: Of course I've tried...1 PC under win7, 1 laptop under win7 and 1 laptop under Ubuntu...

Comment: Okay friend, now, I face that problem on my windows 7 laptop. I solve it by unchecking "Use hardware acceleration when available" in this chrome setting page => chrome://settings/search#hardware

Comment: Now, Chrome render your website without blurry text.

Comment: Yeah! Thanx a lot, man! For me everything works fine now too... But still, interesting will this issue be fixed in future built of Chrome or not... Simple user do not know anything about hardware setting of Crome...they just see weird picture and dislike web-site...
Any wat, thanx for your help!

Comment: I'm sorry for responding lately...Yahh man no problem. If you should face any bugs in Chrome, you can also leave your question on [Google Chrome Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/chrome)